# Why are my Symfony/Doctrine2 entites different from my CI/D2 ones ? (Ultimately, What is the difference between Doctrine 2 and Doctrine 2 ORM ?)

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I know this seems like a very basic question but PLEASE before voting down, read until the end.

This question came to my mind when using Codeigniter along with Doctrine 2.

I have noticed that, at least when using annotation, the synthax is slightly different than when using Doctrine 2 with Symfony2 and  I am wondering why.

I'll provide an example:

This is a class in Symfony2 with a Many To One relation:

```
<?php

namespace Pondip\LakeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Lake
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pondip_lake")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Pondip\LakeBundle\Entity\LakeRepository")
 */
class Lake
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @Assert\Type(type="Pondip\LakeBundle\Entity\Venue")
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pondip\LakeBundle\Entity\Venue")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="venue_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $venue;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var text
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pondip\UserAccountBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdBy;
```

please pay attention to all the @ORM\ everywhere.

Now, when using this with codeigniter2/Doctrine2.3.0 I have Mapping errors in my console.
But, when following some tuts, I ended up removing all of the ORM\ (and the corresponding use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM) and it worked.

This work :

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

/**
 * Friend Model
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="friend")
 * @author  Miles Yohann Merran <hello_miles@hotmail.com>
 */
class Friend
{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=32, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $picture;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $genre;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friends")
     * @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $user;


    /**
     * @var datetime $date
     *
     * @Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $date;
```

When this doesn't work (pay attention at the ORM)

```
<?php

namespace Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Friend Model
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="friend")
 * @author  Miles Yohann Merran <hello_miles@hotmail.com>
 */
class Friend
{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=32, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $picture;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $genre;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friends")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $user;


    /**
     * @var datetime $date
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $date;
```

Why ? What is the difference ?

EDIT: To be exact, I tried 2 entites, with the same structure, one with @ORM\ before avery annotation  sentence, and one without. The one with @ORM\ wasn't managed properly by Doctrine 2 when using the terminal commands and the one without works perfectly well. I wasn't able to find any documentation about that even if I clearly see both in the doc and the src that there is Doctrine Common, Doctrine ORM and Doctrine DBAL. Aren't they compatible between each other ? how to properly manage this difference ? especially when working with another framework than S (like CI2)

Thank you

Comment: @ Orm is something that Symfony 2 configured.  You will also notice the @ Assert for Symfony 2 validation.  Adding these annotation namespaces allows both types of annotations to co-exist without intefering with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, in symfony the doctrine annotation reader is an [`AnnotationReader`](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationReader.php), whereas in CI using the doctrine [`Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php#L113-L118) helper, you have the [`SimpleAnnotationReader`](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/SimpleAnnotationReader.php) by default.

You should be able to have the same behavior as in symfony by passing `false` to the 5th argument `$useSimpleAnnotationReader` of [`Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php#L113-L118).

Comment: Since I changed it, this query doesn't work anymore : `$user = $em->getRepository( 'Entity\User' )->findOneBy( array( 'email' => $email, 'password' => $pwd ) );` any idea why ? It throws out a SQL Synthax error ...

Comment: Since you accepted the answer then you should probably make a new question.  However, trying to pull @ Orm out of Symfony will only lead to kicking harmless puppies out of frustration.  If you need to share entity files then switch to using yaml for your mappings.